# How to convert from tuple (Option<&str>, Option<&str>) to tuple (Option<String>, Option<String>)?

Tags: rust, tuples

I'm trying to get from this:

```rust
let a: Option<&str> = Some("foo");
let b: Option<String> = a.map(|s| s.to_string());
```

to a tuple form:

```rust
let c: (Option<&str>, Option<&str>) = (Some("bar"), Some("baz"));
let d: (Option<String>, Option<String>) = c.map(|s| (s.0.to_string(), s.1.to_string()));
```

```bash
7 |     let d: (Option<String>, Option<String>) = c.map(|s| (s.0.to_string(), s.1.to_string()));
  |                                                 ^^^ `(Option<&str>, Option<&str>)` is not an iterator
  |
  = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `(Option<&str>, Option<&str>): Iterator`
          which is required by `&mut (Option<&str>, Option<&str>): Iterator
```

How can I convert the tuple of optional string slices to a tuple of optional strings using `rust 1.61` or newer?

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=97f9b94c83e8759006d2f2cbe3f95e6c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do as you did when you had two variables:

```rust
let c = (Some("bar"), Some("baz"));
let d = (c.0.map(|s| s.to_string()), c.1.map(|s| s.to_string()));
```

Comment: Thank you, I was already thinking about complicated match expressions but this solution is more elegant.

Comment: Minor nit: I think `str::to_owned` is better when you want to produce an equivalent `String` from a `&str`. `to_string` is part of the `ToString` trait, which is blanket-implemented for anything implanting `Display`. In other words, `to_string` really means "give me a human-readable version of this variable"; it's only a coincidence that for `str` this coincides with "convert to an owned `String`"

Comment: @BallpointBen I agree with the general idea, but in practice literal `String`s are almost always built either with `String::from` or with `ToString::to_string` from a `&str`. It's true that `to_owned` would make more sense but it seems that it's not what is usually used, and since both are equivalent (and probably will always be since the Rust dev team cares a lot about backward compatibility), it's not much of an issue.